# Issue when adding class based on scrollTop() and using position sticky for navbar

Tags: jquery, css, sticky

I am trying to build a Navbar where the padding shrinks as the user starts to scroll. The shrinking is done by simply adding a class to the header element on scroll and then changing the padding in CSS.

The issue I am having is that when I scroll to around 50px where the 'shrink' class is added to the  the toggleClass gets stuck in a loop making the navbar flip between the two css properties really quickly. This can be fixed by applying a 'position: fixed' to the header element instead of 'sticky' however I need to use 'position:sticky' in this case.

```js
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function() {
  $('header').toggleClass('shrink', $(document).scrollTop() > 50);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

header.shrink {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
}

main {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

main .container {
  background: rgb(34, 193, 195);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(34, 193, 195, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 187, 45, 1) 100%);
  min-height: 6000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="logo">
      Logo
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Content</h2>
  </div>
</main>
```

[Click here for a codepen example](https://codepen.io/Rubenkretek/pen/xxRdJJo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the size of your element changes and then the browser re-calculates the scrollposition giving you that nice glitch.

This is a known bug: [chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=734461), [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1374171)

Update: The only "solution" I've found is to have an outer element that NEVER changes size (in your case the header). That one is made sticky and it's height should be defined by height + bottom margin (so that it takes up the right amount of initial space in the document and dont trigger the recalculation.

```js
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function() {
  $('header').toggleClass('shrink', $(document).scrollTop() > 50);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  overflow-anchor: none;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom:80px;
}

header.shrink .sticky-wrapper {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.sticky-wrapper {
  background: red;
  padding: 50px 0;
  transition: padding 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
}

main {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

main .container {
  background: rgb(34, 193, 195);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(34, 193, 195, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 187, 45, 1) 100%);
  min-height: 6000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="sticky-wrapper">
    <div class="nav-container">
      <div class="logo">
        Logo
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Content</h2>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Great suggestion, however I still get the same issue, only now the change in classes is delayed by the debouncer, so it flashes less frequently.

Comment: Another way to "hack around" it is to add the same difference of pixels in the top of your main tag. That way the recalculation wont happen from the browser

Comment: I did think that but the size changes on scroll so the code would get quite messy wouldn't it?

Comment: Your problem is bugging my head so I ve tried another few options. I updated the code snippet and my response

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and have found another solution that is pretty simple.

The problem was that the browser re-calculates scroll position.
I just calculate again after the toggle to neutralize re-calculation by the browser.

Change your javascript code like this:

```js
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function() {
  const originScrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  $('header').toggleClass('shrink', $(document).scrollTop() > 50);
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = originScrollTop;
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work when you use transition.